# In what context would I use the word "availabilities"?

Tags: word-usage

In what context would I use the word “availabilities”?

I believe it is a valid English word, in how could it be used?

Many thanks

Comment: Include the question in the body, apart from the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it's used in scheduling. If a doctor has an open slot in her schedule, that might be called "an availability." Multiple openings would be multiple "availabilities." This is not in common usage, though, and seems to be an invented euphemism used in corporate speak or other places where one wishes to sound important by using big new words for things whose already existent words aren't snazzy enough (I editorialize here).

Comment: What would be a good synonym for "availabilities" that doesn't cause the interlocutor to think one wishes to sound important?

Comment: "Slots" or "openings" should work fine in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

*availability*: *n* the quality of being at hand when needed
Being a noun, it can certainly be pluralized. See usage examples below.

*[availabilities](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/availabilities)*

> Negligible downsizings, bankruptcies or corporate cutbacks of any kinds paired with some leasing in existing **availabilities** to result in a 44% drop in sublease offerings to 514,160 SF or just 12% of the county's total available space.
>   *Office market generates strong year in 2004* by *Real Estate Weekly*
>
> 4 percent, upsetting five straight quarters of diminishing **availabilities**.
>   *First quarter shows mixed results for Westchester/Fairfield markets by Real Estate Weekly*